# Basic PHP program not working with WAMP. Code displayed as text instead of executed

Tags: php, xampp, wamp

**Here is my code:**

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Vowel Checker</title>
      </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Is It A Vowel?</h1>
      <form action="Vowels.php" method="post">
        <p>Your Letter:</p><input type="text" name="letter">
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
      <?php
        $l = $_POST['letter'];
        $l = strtolower($l);
        if ($l != ""){
          switch ($l) {
            case "a":
            case "e":
            case "i":
            case "o":
            case "u":
              echo '<h1 style="color: green;">Your letter is a vowel</h1>';
              break;
            case "y":
              echo '<h1 style="color: orange;">Your letter is sometimes a vowel</h1>';
              break;
            default:
              echo '<h1 style="color: red;">Your letter is not a vowel</h1>';
              break;
          } 
        }
      ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**If you use** http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php and set $l equal to a letter (since my form submission doesn't work with online compilers) to test it out, **it works properly**. But I've tired JSfiddle, WAMP, and XAMPP, and it hasn't worked. I made the code on a *mac* using sublime text and MAMP.

**This is how the program runs** from WAMP/XAMPP in Google Chrome (I've also tried Firefox and IE):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzPHh.png

And if you look in inspect element, you see **it has added a comment in the opening php tag**:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fENC7.png

I find this very strange it this error is ***impeding my school work*** =[ so id *really* **love** some help.

thank!!!

Comment: Notice the URL? You're not invoking it through the server, you're actually opening the file directly. You want to do something like `localhost/index.php` or `127.0.0.1/index.php` (which is the loopback IP address)

Comment: Thank you very much my friend I have it running now! Perhaps you can see my comment on Spork's answer? I have a small error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juding from https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzPHh.png, you are opening the PHP file directly in a browser.

What's going wrong here is that you are not accessing a web server (in your XAMPP case this is Apache) and therefore no PHP interpreter is being called. What you end up seeing is what shows up as a browser that interprets a text file (parsing HTML from it, and not recognizing the PHP, nor interpreting it as code).

Access this file through your `http://localhost/` . Go from there. If you have no webserver, read up on webservers first.

Comment: OMG i feel so stupid haha yes i got this to work almost straight away!

Comment: although the program works how i intend, i still get this error (on internet explorer) http://i.imgur.com/tA1v0M2.png
this is line 18: $l = $_POST['letter'];

Comment: @user2756012 It's because on first load, `$_POST` is empty because you haven't posted any data to it. You should only attempt to grab something from `$_POST` if you know its there (i.e. after the form is submitted).

Comment: okay that makes sense i guess. sorry if you already kind of explained this but how can I avoid this error? thanks

Comment: Don't read from $_POST until something has been POSTed. Try having a go at it, google around a bit about POST, the community here will be able to help you if you get stuck on document a question like you did here.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at your screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzPHh.png . Your path in the browser is not correct. go to "localhost" in your browser and then navigate to your project folder.
"localhost/YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY/Vowels.php"

Comment: Yes i have it going now thank you for your time! lovely for you to help